# Disallow to download a file via SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp

Users are only allowed via SFTP and only with pubkey. There is 1 UNIX user on the system and many ssh pubkeys in the `authorized_keys` file.

Q: How can I prevent the users to download the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file? I know it is needed for login, but I want to restrict them, so they will not know who is allowed on the SFTP server.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your server to find this file somewhere else (out of the users home) using for example:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
```

Still these files would be readable for the users. The other possibility is to use

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/sbin/get_user_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser dedicated_user
```

And the command `/usr/sbin/get_user_keys` will fetch the keys for users from different location (for example the above) using dedicated user. The logging user will not be able to see the other keys.